# Generating a list of which files changed between hg versions

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I want to generate a list of which files changed between two revisions in a given directory in Mercurial.

In particular, I am not interested in *what* changed, but *which files* changed in that directory.

E.g., supposing that between `then` and `otherthen`, only 2 files changed:

```
>hg hypothetical-command -r then:otherthen
foo.baz
bar.baz
>
```

What's the hypothetical command? I've tried diff and log, but I can't see how to convince them to do it: either I get the patch(diff), or I get the whole repo(log).

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```
hg status --rev x:y
```

where `x` and `y` are desired revision numbers (or tag or branch names).

If you are using the terminal in windows add `hg status --rev x:y`**`> your-file.txt`** to save the list to a file.

Comment: To only see changes in the current directory: `hg status --rev x:y .`

Comment: To see the changes in the latest revision: 
`hg status --rev .^`

Comment: To get just the list of filenames (and no prefix character indicating the type of change), append `-n`, i.e. `hg status --rev x:y -n`

Comment: `hg status --change .` lists the changed files in `.` - same list as `hg status --rev .^` but more directly

Answer (score 15):

**status** is what you need.

But, depending what you mean by "between two revisions", you might also consider using the "**x::y**" (DAG - Directed Acyclic Graph) range.

Given parallel changesets,

`1--2---4
  \---3`

`hg status --rev 1:4`  would return (1,2,3,4),
i.e. anything between and including the endpoints, according to the local, numerical *rev*. This might (and most probably will) return different results in other - though related - repositories!

`hg status --rev 1::4` would return (1,2,4),
i.e. the endpoints, and all changesets which are *descendants* of '1' AND *ancestors* of '4'.

The latter case, x::y, is usually more useful in real-world applications. This is what you get via TortoiseHg\Visual Diff.

---

>hg help revsets:

> "x::y"
>     A DAG range, meaning all changesets that are descendants of x and
>     ancestors of y, including x and y themselves. If the first endpoint is
>     left out, this is equivalent to "ancestors(y)", if the second is left
>     out it is equivalent to "descendants(x)".

Comment: Maybe you need to include explicitly the command so your answer isn't dependent of the other and more fool-proof. Something like "Yes, status is what you need. For example `hg status --rev x::y`".