# mercurial generate file name only diff

Tags: mercurial, diff, dvcs

Is there a way to generate a diff in mercurial that only gives the file names? I'd like to do something like

```
diff -r 1 --file-names-only
```

and get something like

```
+AddedFile.java
-RemovedFile.java
/ChangedFile.java
/AnotherChangedFile.java
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a list of which files changed between hg versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024510/generating-a-list-of-which-files-changed-between-hg-versions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you just want to see added/removed/changed files, etc. Thought it was something more complex. Shouldn't `hg stat` do what you need, then?

Comment: It helps, but still not exactly what I want. It shows insertions and deletions. I want to know that overall status of the file itself. Thanks though!

Comment: Oh, wait, I now see what you want

Comment: Bingo. That's exactly what I want! Thank you much. I knew it couldn't be difficult.

Comment: You got me there for a moment :D. I assumed `status` is a basic command that everybody knows, because it's basically the same command for and CVS, SubVersion (I guess Hg used the same to keep things familiar for everyone), and it's explained soon on every tutorial

Answer (score 16):

This should do the trick

```
hg status --rev revision1:revision2
```

Where revision1 and revision2 can be a changeset, tag etc.

Comment: Thank you. The accepted answer wasn't very clear. This doesn't follow the same syntax as `hg diff` at all.

Comment: This also lists files that are changed then changed back. (no change)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need stat info, then this output is a lot cleaner:

```
hg log --style status
# git log --name-status
```

If you want don't like the format of "status" style it can be customized even further using templates:

```
hg log --template "{rev} {subject}\n{files % '  {file}\n'}\n"
# git log --name-only
```