# List files that are different between two hg changesets

Tags: mercurial, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a list of which files changed between hg versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024510/generating-a-list-of-which-files-changed-between-hg-versions)

`hg diff -r 5 -r 10` will give the differences between revisions 5 and 10. But I want to see specifically just a list of files that are different - I don't want to see the full diffs. Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`hg status` can do this.

The main purpose of `hg status` is showing modified files in the working directory (in comparison to the last commit).
But you can use the `--rev` parameter to let it compare two specific revisions instead, like this:

```
hg status --rev 5 --rev 10
```

Comment: n:m range for revisions just a little nicer and readable

Comment: @LazyBadger: Thank you, I didn't know this! I already saw it in the question Martin Geisler linked above.