# Corrupt hg log output, could it be true?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Please, observe:

```
c:\dev\shunra.old>hg log -r ecf --template '{files}' |tr " " "\012" | findstr ProductLicenseFeature

c:\dev\shunra.old>hg log -r ecf --template '{file_mods}' |tr " " "\012" | findstr ProductLicenseFeature
Application/ShunraLicense/src/com/shunra/common/license/ProductLicenseFeature.java

c:\dev\shunra.old>
```

So, what do we have here? **ecf** is the prefix of a revision, which is the result of merging two other revisions:

```
c:\dev\shunra.old>hg parents -r ecf --style compact
2430:2420   94067e763d55   2013-01-14 12:17 +0200   gilad
  Marge changes from S4HP9.0 branch

2443   a8f3e0a226eb   2013-01-15 00:48 +0200   genkor
  For empty locations and configurations take default content from templates.


c:\dev\shunra.old>
```

The merge was done in TortoiseHg. The strangest thing is that the particular file is not displayed in the change list, which corresponds to the `{files}` template keyword.

But it was changed, and indeed the `{file_mods}` template keyword does show it.

The net result is that we cannot trust the change list presented by TortoiseHg, which is a bad thing.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mercurial_general/2I-e-MMk98g). Maybe this file was automatically resolved during the merge?
Quote from there:

```
A (automatic) merge will from one point of view not introduce any file
changes - only propagate changes that already has been made. From
another point of view it will introduce a number of "new" file changes
in another context and thus changes a lot of files. An intermediate
point of view is when both sides of a merge touches the same file and
the merge thus produces a combined file where the total content will be
new and unique.
```

Comment: +1 This is most likely the cause. But it does not make it any better, because the file is really changed, but it is not obvious at all and thus misleading. Any way to make it surface in the changes?

Comment: Dont know really. Maybe `hg status --rev X:Y` could help in that case? Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2024591/1000551)