# Generating a list of directories containing files changed between revisions

Tags: mercurial

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2024591/3959259) that I can do

```
hg status --rev x:y
```

to list files that have been changed between revisions `x` and `y`. Is there a way to get not the indiviual files but only the directories in which they are contained?

For example if the above command would yield

```
A Foo\Bar\SomeFile.txt
A Foo\Bar\AnotherFile.cs
M Baz\AnotherFile.txt
```

I want to get

```
Foo\Bar
Baz
```

instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a ready-to use solution (see end-notes), just hints

- You can use templates for changing output format of `hg st`, as it can done for any "log-like" hg commands (see `-T` option)
- in template you can filter output (filenames) with filter "dirname", which'll strip filename part of file

but I tried it and discovered (on my repos) some "oddities" (and *expected* troubles)

End-notes:

1. While default output of `hg st` eliminates duplicate filenames (if they appear) in result, your template will not (again, "by default")
2. I saw wrong (totally wrong) result of templated output for the same range of status

good

```
>hg st --rev 1170:tip
M hggit\__init__.py
M hggit\compat.py
M hggit\git_handler.py
M hggit\gitdirstate.py
M hggit\hg2git.py
M tests\test-illegal-contents.t
```

my

```
>hg st --rev 1170:tip --template "{files % '{file}\n'}"
hggit/__init__.py
hggit/__init__.py
hggit/__init__.py
hggit/__init__.py
hggit/__init__.py
hggit/__init__.py
```

(six times files *from tip only* instead of range)

3. Even with `hg log -T` instead of st (which give **all files**) you'll have problem from p.1: "more than one file-entry in output for the same file"

Comment: Your idea with templates worked for me. I could filter out duplicates via the shell (PowerShell in my case) like so: `hg status --rev 1:^ --template "{files % '{file|dirname}\n'}" | Sort-Object -Unique`

Comment: @ThomasSchremser - good. You can now a) convert this command into shell-alias for simplicity b) maybe add conditional output of "/" instead of "" for repo-root /just for better readability/